# Error en código jQuery

Tags: jquery-validate

tengo este codigo que su objetivo es que valide si un usuario escrib de forna correcta texto. Por ejemplo, la estructura que debe tener ese texto seria "PG-###" y np logro encontrar el error. Entodo momento me muestra que lo escrito por el usuario es incorrecto, aunque lo escriba bien. Si tienen algun tipo de pregunta, se lo puedo responder. Gracias de antemano.
PD:  La funcion "validarNumero()" no tiene ningun tipo de problema.

```
$("#text_codigo_postgrado").keyup(function(){
        if (!validarCodigo($(this))) {
            $("#alerta_codigo").show();
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#alerta_codigo").hide();
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
            $(this).addClass("is-valid");
            return true;
        }

    })
```

Esta es la función con la que trabaja el código

```
function validarCodigo(codigo){
    var codigoSeparado = codigo.val().split('-');   
    if (codigoSeparado[0] != "PG" || !validarNumero(codigoSeparado[1])) {
        codigo.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿El texto: PG-PG-111  seria valido?

Comment: Por otro lado la función validarCodigo  parece estar incorrecta. En la primera invocación recibe un objeto jquery y en la invocación recursiva recibe una cadena. Por otro lado no veo la necesidad de lo recursivo al menos no como esta puesto pues en cada invocación se hace un split por el '-' y eso debería hacerse solo una vez.

Comment: El evento KeyUp se dispara a cada tecla de modo que al introducir P o PG la función de validación va a fallar. Además, la pregunta que hace @AlvaroC. en su primer comentario. Debes usar indexOf('-') para saber que esté en la posición 2 (cuenta en base 0) y, sólo si la longitud de la cadena es mayor que 3 hacer validación.

Comment: PG-PG-111 no puede ser código válido. Entonces k sugerencias puedes darme??? Tenis pensado k codigoSeparado era un arreglo. Así pensé k trabajaba split

Comment: Me puedes decir cómo podría hacerlo con indexOf??

Answer (score 0):

Como te dicen, lo primero es que el evento keyup se lanza cada vez que se escribe una letra, por lo que sería mejor lanzar la comprobación cuando el usuario ha acabado de escribir, por ejemplo con focusout. Además, yo haría que validarCodigo no tuviera interacción con el objeto jquery y solo informase si el código es correcto o incorrecto.

```
//Para probarlo yo he creado la funcion validarNumero así:
function validarNumero(numero){
    if(isNaN(numero))
        return false;
    else return true;
}
//Cambio el evento keyup por focusout
$("#text_codigo_postgrado").focusout(function(){
    //Le paso el valor a validarCodigo, no el objeto jquery
    if (!validarCodigo($(this).val())) {
       $("#alerta_codigo").show();
       //Como en validar código no tengo acceso al objeto jquery
       //el focus lo hago aquí
       $(this).focus();
       return false;
    } else {
       $("#alerta_codigo").hide();
       $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
       $(this).addClass("is-valid");
       return true;
    }

});

function validarCodigo(codigo){
    //codigo ahora es una cadena
    var codigoSeparado = codigo.split('-');
    
    if (codigoSeparado[0] != "PG" || !validarNumero(codigoSeparado[1])) {
        //Quito codigo.focus()
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lo he probado y me funciona correctamente.
Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Utilicé el código, pero veo k solo m está validando hasta PG, lo demás no lo válida. Sin contar k probé lo k dijo @Alvaro C con respecto a PG-PG- y lo acepta sin problema alguno y no debería ser así. Que pudiera hacer para arreglar esos problemas??

Comment: Hola, el código que te he pasado funciona correctamente, si escribes PG-PG... en el input lo da como no válido, solo da válido el texto PG-### siendo ### números. ¿Lo has copiado exactamente igual?

Comment: Si, tenía pensado arreglar el mío con ese y no lo hice, copié y pegue el tuyo. Me reconoce cuando escribo PG  y lo valida, pero la parte numérica no y PG-PG- lo sigue validando como correcto. Aún tengo tu código en un txt cómo backup. No sé cuál pueda ser el problema pq el código lo veo muy bien.

Comment: Debe ser que la función validarNumero no te va bien, ¿puedes poner el código de esa función?

Comment: La función de validarNumero() k tengo yo trabaja bien pq está implementando en otros input y no está dando bateo. De todas formas yo puse el k tú pusiste en tu código, para no dejar de descartar